# Protobuf with Multidimensional Array

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, protobuf-net

I'm working on saving and loading for a game being developed in c# xna. I have a long list of class arrays that I'm trying to serialize and im coming across a problem with one of them. Ive done the class like the following

```
 [ProtoContract]
public class CompleteTile
{
    int _id;
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int ID
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set { _id = value; }
    }

    bool _Passable;
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public bool Passable
    {
        get { return _Passable; }
        set { _Passable = value; }
    }
```

I can successfully serialize it using

```
using (var stream = File.OpenWrite("" + saveDestination + "level.dat"))
        { Serializer.Serialize(stream, Globals.levelArray); }
```

But when I try to deserialize I get the following - Type is not expected, and no contract can be inferred: GameName1.CompleteTile[,,]

Deserilization code -

```
        using (var stream = File.OpenRead("" + loadDestination + "level.dat"))
        { Globals.levelArray = Serializer.Deserialize<CompleteTile[, ,]>(stream); }
```

I suspect this is due to it being a multidimensional array but I'm not sure, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Multidimensional arrays are not supported (they don't exist in the protobuf specification) - you *should* have got a more specific error though - I will look into why it didn't tell you exactly that (because: that message does exist in the code)

Comment: Thanks, I thought this was the reason although I was expecting it to fail serializing but it only fails on desalinization. Do you have any suggestions on the best way to proceed? Its multiple 500x500 grids of tiles so the array looks like Globals.levelArray[level,x,y] was taking up to 2 minutes and 350mb to serialize using binaryformatter :/

Answer (score 3):

As already mentioned, protobuf does not support multidimensional arrays. However, you can circumvent this limitation by transforming the multidimensional array into a 1D array + a dimensional array of integers. To easy the pain, I use a few extensions

```
public static class Extensions
{

    #region Multidimensional array handling

    public static ProtoArray<T> ToProtoArray<T>(this Array array)
    {
        // Copy dimensions (to be used for reconstruction).
        var dims = new int[array.Rank];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Rank; i++) dims[i] = array.GetLength(i);
        // Copy the underlying data.
        var data = new T[array.Length];
        var k = 0;
        array.MultiLoop(indices => data[k++] = (T) array.GetValue(indices));

        return new ProtoArray<T> {Dimensions = dims, Data = data};
    }

    public static Array ToArray<T>(this ProtoArray<T> protoArray)
    {
        // Initialize array dynamically.
        var result = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(T), protoArray.Dimensions);
        // Copy the underlying data.
        var k = 0;
        result.MultiLoop(indices => result.SetValue(protoArray.Data[k++], indices));

        return result;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Array extensions

    public static void MultiLoop(this Array array, Action<int[]> action)
    {
        array.RecursiveLoop(0, new int[array.Rank], action);
    }

    private static void RecursiveLoop(this Array array, int level, int[] indices, Action<int[]> action)
    {
        if (level == array.Rank)
        {
            action(indices);
        }
        else
        {
            for (indices[level] = 0; indices[level] < array.GetLength(level); indices[level]++)
            {
                RecursiveLoop(array, level + 1, indices, action);
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion
}

[ProtoContract]
public class ProtoArray<T>
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int[] Dimensions { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public T[] Data { get; set; }
}
```

and persist each multidimensional arrays as a ProtoArray.

Comment: Great solution! Maybe ProtoArray members can be signed as packed array [ProtoMember(1, IsPacked = true)]